# Add Column to filtered dataset

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have created a DataFrame using the below code. I have grouped by 'Sales_Year' and counted the values in 'LATEST_LAND_SALE_PRICE'. My issue is I'd like to add other unaltered columns to the dataset. Below I've tried to add 'PLANNING_JURISDICTION' but instead of keeping the original values of the column it is counting them.

Code and Output below.

```
count = data[['PLANNING_JURISDICTION','Sales_Year','LATEST_LAND_SALE_PRICE']].groupby('Sales_Year').count().reset_index()

count.rename(columns={'LATEST_LAND_SALE_PRICE':'Sales_Count'}, inplace=True)

#Output#

   Sales_Year  PLANNING_JURISDICTION  Sales_Count
0        2017                    428          428
1        2018                    451          451
2        2019                    440          439
3        2020                    366          366
```

How I do I add other columns but keep their original values?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to add more columns to the output u have right now?

Comment: Yes. Planning Jurisdiction should have string values(e.g. RO, ZB). So I'd like to add this column and others to the DataFrame

Comment: do you want to add for example `428RO` `451ZB` like this?

Comment: No just the original column values i.e RO, ZB.

Comment: you should include  (a small sample of) your `data`, otherwise we have no idea what was in the 'original' column. Please follow rules here when doing so: [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Also please provide expected output so we understand better what you want